# Font style settings not taking effect in KDE Plasma

Tags: kde, fonts

I have recently installed KDE Plasma 5.18 in my desktop PC running Ubuntu 20.04.
I didn't like the large size fonts that came pre-configured with Plasma, so I have changed the font settings as follows:
[image]

The problem is that no KDE apps are respecting the font style changes, but the GTK based apps do.
Here is a screenshot of Google Chrome's title bar with font style applied properly:
[image]

And, here is Dolphin, with the font size not applied:
[image]
Not even the Panel respects the font settings:
[image]

I have searched a lot, but my searches gave irrelevant results. Is this a known bug of Plasma?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue. There was a `.gtkrc-2.0` file in my home folder. On viewing the contents I have found that the font size was set to 11. I had to delete that file. After re-login font size is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I found a fairly comprehensive guide to changing font settings [with this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/279833/293199). I'm regularly using KDE and Gnome apps, some apps not even in the Ubuntu 20.04 repo. I found the `qt5ct` and `gnome-tweaks` tools complement each other well for maintaining control over font settings.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the 'Force Font DPI' option under System Settings, Fonts has solved a problem with GTK and KDE apps having different font sizes.

I have two screens with different DPI and have set it to the DPI of my primary display.